# Recorrer DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente código para recorrer un `DataGridView` en el evento `DoubleClick`, cuando selecciono la fila y hago el dobleclick me arroja siempre el mensaje aunque el valor de la columna stockeable sea `"S"`, es decir lo que necesito es que si el valor de la celda de la columna stockeable es `"S"`, me copie el parametro al formulario `fjdCompras` pero si contiene otro dato distinto de `"S"` que no me copie nada y arroje el mensaje de error.

¿Alguien me podria ayudar con el código? Muchas gracias

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataListado.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["stockeable"].Value) == "S")
    {
        fjdCompras frmComprasA = fjdCompras.GetInstancia();
        string parCA1;
        parCA1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["idproducto"].Value);
        frmComprasA.setProducto(parCA1);
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("El artículo seleccionado no es stockeable", "Consulta de Artículos" + MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Vos queres revisar toda la grilla? o solo donde hizo doble click, porque tu codigo recorre toda la grilla

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que recordar, que el evento [`CellDoubleClick`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CellDoubleClick);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) recibe un argumento de tipo [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), el cual posee la propiedad [`RowIndex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), por lo cual, no necesitamos recorrer el `DataGridView` completo, ya sabemos exactamente cual fue la fila en la que el usuario ralizo el dobleclick.

Vamos al caso práctico..

Primero, inscribimos el DataGridView al evento

```
dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick;
```

Luego, definimos el método que controlará al evento

```
private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Obtengo el DataGridView que generó el evento.
    DataGridView gridView = (DataGridView)sender;
    //Obtengo la fila desde la cual se produjo el evento.
    DataGridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //En caso de que la columna stockeable, tenga el valor s...
    if (row.Cells["stockeable"].Value == "S")
    {
        //actúo con el IDProducto de la fila..
        string idProducto = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["idproducto"].Value);
    }
    //Caso contrario..
    else
    {
        //actúo en caso de no ser stockeable.
    }
}
```